# Ada 95 Tasking: How can I send a rendezvous from one instantiated task to another that is in a separate instantiated Task?

Tags: task, scheduled-tasks, ada

I have created defined 2 Task Types, and instantiated them in the main program.

How do I send rendezvous between the separate tasks?

```ada
Procedure Task_Prog is
    task type Task_one is
        entry Redezvous_One;
    end Task_one;

    task type Task_Two is
        entry Redezvous_Two;
    end Task_Two;

    task body Task_one is
        Finished : Boolean := False;
    begin
        while not Finished loop
            accept Redezvous_One do
                finished := True;
                Task_Instantiation_B.Redezvous_Two;
            end Redezvous_One;
        end loop;
    end Task_one;

    task body Task_Two is
        Finished : Boolean := False;
    begin
        while not Finished loop
            accept Redezvous_Two do 
                finished := True;
            end Redezvous_Two;
        end loop;
    end Task_Two;

    Task_Instantiation_A : Task_one;
    Task_Instantiation_B: Task_Two;
begin
    Task_Instantiation_A.Redezvous_One;
end Task_Prog;
```

Compilation Error is:

> task_prog.ada: Error: line 17 col 4 LRM:4.1(3), Direct name, Task_Instantiation_B, is not visible, Ignoring future references

I'm looking for one task to be able to pipe commands/rendezvous to other tasks that have been instantiated.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Simply moving the task instantiations above the task body declarations will make them visible to the task bodies, and with this change, your example compiles successfully.

That is...

```ada
Procedure Task_Prog is
   task type Task_one is
       entry Rendezvous_One;
   end Task_one;

   task type Task_Two is
       entry Rendezvous_Two;
   end Task_Two;

   Task_Instantiation_A : Task_one;
   Task_Instantiation_B : Task_Two;

   task body Task_one is
   ... etc
```

This may not be compatible with your larger problem. If not, then add further details or constraints to the question.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to realize that everything in `Accept`/`do`...`end` is the rendezvous, so calling `Task_Instantiation_B.Redezvous_Two` inside `Redezvous_One` is likely to deadlock. (Given it's a task type, you could have a different task than the one calling in `Redezvous_One`, which would solve that problem.)

So, change this:

```
    while not Finished loop
        accept Redezvous_One do
            finished := True;
            Task_Instantiation_B.Redezvous_Two;
        end Redezvous_One;
    end loop;
```

to this:

```
    while not Finished loop
        accept Redezvous_One do
            finished := True;
        end Redezvous_One;
    end loop;
    Task_Instantiation_B.Redezvous_Two;
```

Secondly you need to reorder your task-spec and bodies:

```
Task type Task_one is --...
Task type Task_two is --...

Task body Task_one is --...
Task body Task_two is --...
```

should do it. -- Now, if you're not going to have multiples change the `task type` to just plain `task` and you should be good.